# Calling textbox within a static method

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a problem when referencing a TextBox within a static function.
To give an idea see the code below:
I created a MainForm which includes a Windows Form with buttons and text boxes.
The text boxes are filled with strings.
In the main class below I use CheckInput() as a main loop. This function is called from various callback functions (press buttons) and worked fine.
During development I needed to call the same function from an other class (InitForm). To do this I had to use the MainForm class name first. To do this I also had to use the 'static' keyword before the CheckInput() function. But suddenly the TextBox reference was not working. An error was given. To solve this I created an instance of the MainForm:

```
MainForm c = new MainForm();
     if ( c.TextBox.Text != "")   
     {
         DoSomeAction();
     }
```

All errors were gone!

But..... When debugging the code, the Textbox value is gone! It seems when creating a new instance the textbox value is not inhereted.
What can I do to have the Original textbox value??

John
Main class

```
 public class MainForm : Form
    {
    private int ………… some variables

    // constructor
    public MainForm ()
    {
    Init();
    }
    }

    // Method
    public static bool CheckInput()
    {
    if ( TextBox.Text != "")   
    {
    DoSomeAction();
    }
    }


    Another class

    public class InitForm : Form
    {
    private int …………………….. some variables



     // constructor
     public InitForm()
     {
     Init();
                }
     // Method
     private void Button_Click(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
     {
     MainForm.CheckInput();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has been reduced for brevity.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    private void DisplaySecondForm()
    {
        using (var frm = new SecondForm(this))
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

public class SecondForm : Form
{
    private readonly MainForm _mainForm;

    public SecondForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private void InvokeSomeActionOnMainForm()
    {
        _mainForm.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.